# Inject a list of objects to play application context

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice, playframework-2.2

In my project I have bunch of animal objects, for example:

some of them have dependency injection:

```
class Monkey @Inject() (wsClient: WSClient, configuration: Configuration) extends Animal {
    ...
}
```

and some not:

```
class Giraffe extends Animal {
    ...
}
```

In my `AnimalsService` class I need a list of all the animal objects instances,

Currently my service is getting the list of people as a dependency injection:

```
class AnimalsService @Inject() (animals: List[Animal]) {
    // here I can use animals as my desire
}
```

and then I have a binding class that bind it:

```
class Bindings extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[AnimalsService]).toProvider(classOf[AnimalServiceProvider])
  }
}

object Bindings {
  class AnimalServiceProvider @Inject () (giraffe: Giraffe, monkey: Monkey ...) extends Provider[AnimalsService] {
    override def get: AnimalsService = {
      new AnimalsService(List(giraffe,monkey...))
    }
  }
}
```

This works perfectly, but what I would prefer is to have somehow to add the list to my application context as the app loads so I don't need to do it this way....

This current solution also means I need to add new animals to `AnimalServiceProvider` constructor and to here  new `AnimalsService(List(giraffe,monkey...))` every time I need a new animal, and that will be happened constantly...

What will be the best way of handling this kind of situation?

I thought maybe using `@Named` annotation of guice but not sure if its the right way or how to name a list of objects this way...

Answer (score 0):

I would do a Singleton bean that has the list and a method to add definitions

```
class AnimalsService @Inject() () {
    val animals: List[Animal]
    def addAnimal(animal: Animal) {
        ....
    }
    // here I can use animals as my desire
}
```

Then in each module that needs an animal would need an extra singleton with [Eager bindings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#eager-bindings)

```
class MonkeyConfigurator @Inject() (animalsService: AnimalsService) extends Animal {
    animalsService.add(this) //Or anything
    // here I can use animals as my desire
}
```

Comment: Just a quick idea, there are some details missing, ill try to complement after i get home.